# sql query for the following

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

1. PERSON - Email ID, Phone No, Address, Name, Age, Sex
2. ORDER - No of orders, Recipe, Ingredients, Email ID, Order ID, Order Status
3. ADDRESS - Address, Store Location, Mobile No

Suppose these are the three tables in a database and the respective columns.

what will be the query for getting the recipe which has the highest sale in each store?

i used this query but it shows half the result.

```
select distinct Store_Location, Recipe, No_of_Orders 
from [ORDER] 
join PERSON on [ORDER].Email_ID = PERSON.Email_ID 
join ADDRESS on PERSON.Address = ADDRESS.Address
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far

Comment: i used this query but it shows half the result.       select distinct Store_Location, Recipe, No_of_Orders from [ORDER] join PERSON on [ORDER].Email_ID = PERSON.Email_ID join ADDRESS on PERSON.Address = ADDRESS.Address

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
select distinct Store_Location, Recipe, No_of_Orders 
from [ORDER] As o
join PERSON  As p on o.Email_ID = p.Email_ID 
join ADDRESS As a on p.Address  = a.Address
WHERE No_of_Orders = (
    select MAX(o2.No_of_Orders)
    from [ORDER] As o2
    join PERSON  As p2 on o2.Email_ID = p2.Email_ID 
    join ADDRESS As a2 on p2.Address  = a2.Address
    Where a2.Address = a.Address
    )
```

This query works by comparing the rows of the original query to a subquery that returns the maximum `No_of_Orders` for the current row's store.  If they match, then this must be the row of "*the recipe which has the highest sale for this store*", so we keep it, otherwise we exclude it from the final rowset.

The `As o`, `As o2` bits are called "Table Aliases". They are a way to give a local name to each different usage of a table within a query.  They are necessary here because in the subquery we are re-querying the same tables as in the outer query and we need to be able to distinguish which ones we mean for each column we reference.

Comment: this definitely gives the required result. But i cant quite understand the statement after the 'where'. So please can u explain